# Difficulty in understanding the proof of measurable functions

Tags: real-analysis

If $f$ & $g$ are measurable, then 
show that the integer powers $f^k$ , $k\ge 1$ are measurable.

The proof goes as

Proof:- we consider the following cases:-

I case : k is odd

$ { f^k \gt a} = {f \gt a^{\frac{1}{k}}} $

Now since f is measurable

${ {f\gt a^{\frac{1}{k}}}}$ is measurable & so ${{f^k \gt a}} $ is measurable.

II case:- k is even
Subcase1 :-  $a\lt 0$

In this case   ${f^k \ge a}=E $ where E is domain of f which is measurable.

Subcase II:- $a \gt 0$ 
In similar lines we prove this**

Now I have a doubt regarding how in case II subcase I we get $ { f^k \gt a} $ as set E?

And why such cases considered. when k is odd there are no subcases for a.

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The graph of $x^k$ with $k$ even looks like the quadratic function. So when $a>0$:

$$f^k>a=(f>a^\frac{1}{k})\cup(f<-a^\frac{1}{k})$$

Both $f>a^\frac{1}{k}$ and $f<-a^\frac{1}{k}$ are measurable (as preimages of a [measurable] interval through a measurable function), so their union $f^k>a$ is measurable by the properties of a $\sigma$-algebra.

Comment: Yes I have that proof. My question is about how {$f^k \gt a$} = E?

Comment: when $a<0$ then $f^k(x)>a$ for all $x\in E$. Think for example about $a=-1$ and $k=2$. Is $f^2(x)>-1$ for all $x\in E$?

Comment: Sorry but not getting how that set comes to be E, the domain of f?

Comment: $\{f^2(x)>-1\}=\{x\in E \text{ such that } f^2(x)>-1\}=E$ because the square of $f(x)$ is positive for all $x\in E$, and a positive number is greater than a negative number.

Comment: I got it. Thanks for the answer. It made me clear